# Need a mobile robot simulator that provides easier odometry funtions

Tags: mobile-robot, odometry, simulation

I want a mobile robot to go from a starting position to a goal position. But, I don't want to calculate the pose from encoders. Instead I want to know if there exist such a simulator that provides pose function that makes the work easier, like go_to(x_coordinate, y_coordinate). That means, the robot will automatically calculate its current position and leads itself to the goal position.

Comment: If the robot is automatically calculating the odometry, and the environment is simulated, which part are you developing?

Comment: Please provide more information.  What else do you want / need the simulator to do?  Are you simulating a theoretical perfect robot or do you want wheel slip, 2D or 3D, can it be a simulated version of a common off-the-shelf robot like Khepera or a Pioneer 3-DX or must it by your own robot, what OS will it run on?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am a newbie in this field. I am working on path planning algorithm for mobile robot. For my research, 2D simulation is acceptable. First, I started with Khepera robot using Kiks simulator. I have subdivided my work to small pieces. First job is, I want my robot go from starting position to goal position where no obstacles will be involved. But, when i started with kiks simulator, all i get is encoder values. But, it will be lot easier if i could work with Cartesian(x,y) coordinates. I want such simulator that has large library for odometric calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This closed StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533321/robotics-simulator/2556393) has a long list of simulators and some discussion on them.  Some are simple and 2D only, some are 3D and include rigid body physics simulation.

Comment: I have installed Player/Stage and this is cool for my research. Thanks a lot.